# How to fix call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to deploy a php based application online and getting following error:

```
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in home/spurdes/public_html/testsites/crimebusters/Repository/SQL_Connection.php on line 27.
```

Here is line 27:

```
$this->connection=  mysqli_connect($this->connectionHost,$this->userName,$this->password,$this->dbName);
```

Here is my [phpinfo](http://testsites.spurdesigns.com/crimebusters/phpconfigTest.php)

I dont have access to `php.init`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551398/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: Praveen the differnce is that I dont have access to php.ini

Comment: then change the hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mysqli php extension. Contact to hoster or change hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

I was required to move a website from a commercial web host to a virtual server. I am using php and mysql in IIS on Windows Server 2008. I solved the mysqli_connect problem by doing the following.

- I uncommented extension=php_mysql.dll, extension=php_mysqli.dll, and extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in the php.ini file.

In my php file I had a class with a _construct function that included the mysqli_connect function. This works well in Apache and on the Unix server but not in IIS and Windows Server 2008. Here is the code:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    var $tablename="t_table";       
    var $connection;
    public function __construct() { 
        $this->connection = new MySQLi("host", "user", "password", "dbname", "port")or  die("Error connecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
//functions that use $this->connection and $tablename are here.......
}
?>
```

Note: No other way of assigning a value to $connection worked for me. This is the result of at least 12 hours of internet searching and trial and error coding. I am a novice coder. It may not be pretty but it works. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code in your PHP script

```
 dl("mysqli.so");
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a php vesrion problem

> 1. you replace mysqli_connect() to mysql_connect()
>      or
> 2. contact to server guys to upgrade your version